# Preventing "getCurrentDirectory: resource exhausted (Too many open files)" error

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, parsec, lazy-io

I am trying to run a `Parsec` parser over a whole bunch of small files, and getting an error saying I have too many open files. I understand that I need to use strict IO, but I'm not sure how to do that. This is the problematic code:

```
files = getDirectoryContents historyFolder

hands :: IO [Either ParseError [Hand]]
hands = join $ sequence <$> parseFromFile (many hand) <<$>> files
```

Note: my `<<$>>` function is this:

```
(<<$>>) :: (Functor f1, Functor f2) => (a -> b) -> f1 (f2 a) -> f1 (f2 b)
a <<$>> b = (a <$>) <$> b
```

Comment: The problem is that `parseFromFile` is too lazy, that is the point I would suggest to change, for that you would have to include it.  Besides, using the `pipes` or `conduit` package might be a good idea

Answer (score 6):

I don't know what your `parseFromFile` function looks like right now (probably a good idea to include that in the question), but I'm guessing you're using `Prelude.readFile`, which as @Markus1189 points out includes lazy I/O. To get to strict I/O, you just need a strict `readFile`, such as [Data.Text.IO.readFile](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130829-168/text/Data-Text-IO.html#v%3areadFile).

A streaming data library like `pipes` or `conduit` would allow you to avoid reading the entire file into memory at once, though- to my knowledge- parsec doesn't provide a streaming interface to allow this to happen. attoparsec, on the other hand, does include such a streaming interface, and both pipes and conduit have attoparsec adapter libraries (e.g., [Data.Conduit.Attoparsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-extra-1.1.0/docs/Data-Conduit-Attoparsec.html)).

tl;dr: You probably just need the following helper function:

```
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as TIO

readFileStrict :: FilePath -> IO String
readFileStrict = fmap T.unpack . TIO.readFile
```

Comment: `parseFromFile` is part of parsec, and can be either a [lazy read](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.5/docs/Text-Parsec-ByteString-Lazy.html) with `readFile` from `ByteString.Lazy` or the more [strict variant](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.5/docs/Text-Parsec-ByteString.html) with `bracket openBinaryFile ... hClose`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [BangPatterns](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/bang-patterns.html) language extension to enforce strictness of your IO operations, in this case `parseFromFile`. For example the function `hands` can be changed in:

```hs
hands :: [String] → IO [Either ParseError [Hand]]
hands [] = return []
hands (f:fs) = do
  !res ← parseFromFile hand f
  others ← hands fs
  return (res:others)
```

This version of hands waits for the results of each call of `parseFromFile` before moving to the next file in the list. Once you have this, the problem should disappear. A full working toy example is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative hiding (many)
import Data.Char (isDigit)
import System.Directory (getDirectoryContents)
import System.FilePath ((</>))
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

data Hand = Hand Int deriving Show

hand :: GenParser Char st [Hand]
hand = do
  string "I'm file "
  num ← many digit
  newline
  eof
  return [Hand $ read num]

files :: IO [String]
files = map ("manyfiles" </>)
      ∘ filter (all isDigit) <$> getDirectoryContents "manyfiles"

hands :: [String] → IO [Either ParseError [Hand]]
hands [] = return []
hands (f:fs) = do
  !res ← parseFromFile hand f
  others ← hands fs
  return (res:others)

main :: IO 
main = do
  results ← files >≥ hands
  print results
```